# In Perl, how do I deeply compare data structures serialized to JSON format?

Tags: json, perl, compare, perl-data-structures

I have two data structures in JSON format. They are deeply nested hashes. How can I deeply compare these structures?

Comment: And you should have tried something...

Answer (score 3):

You can decode the JSON using [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/JSON) which just uses [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/JSON%3a%3aXS) if it is installed on your system.

```
use JSON;
use Data::Compare;

my $h1 = JSON->new->utf8->decode($perl_scalar1);
my $h2 = JSON->new->utf8->decode($perl_scalar2);
my $c = Data::Compare->new($h1, $h2);
print 'structures of $h1 and $h are ',
$c->Cmp ? "" : "not ", "identical.\n";
```

Comment: If you're going to `encode` the data, then you might as well just use `eq` instead of Data::Compare.

Comment: what should be in the " " after $c->Cmp ?

Comment: The OP has two JSON strings, you need to decode them to Perl data structures.

Comment: `eq` can't be used as field order not guaranteed.